# Method violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection

When trying to call this function I receive an error

```
function ff(){
 SiteProperties spp = tenant.GetSitePropertiesByUrl(siturl, true);
        ctx.Load(spp);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        spp.SharingCapability=SharingCapabilities.ExternalUserAndGuestSharing;
        spp.Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.VerificationException'
>   occurred in MySomeProgram.exe
>
> Additional information: Method
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.Load: type argument
>   'Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.SiteProperties'
>   violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.

Any ideas as to what could be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurs since there is mismatch between `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll` assembly and the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` assembly versions that are referenced in project.

Ensure the proper version of Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll assembly is referenced.

For example, for SharePoint Online project the the following assembly should be referenced: `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628241/how-to-get-all-site-collections-using-c-sharp-csom

http://todosharepoint.blogspot.com/2014/12/problemas-de-versiones-al-tratar-de.html